# How to give permission as per table value using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I need to give the permission as per the table value to some functions. I am explaining my model below first.

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    """docstring for Permission"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    control_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    find_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am expected table is given below.

```
id   control_reactor      view_reactor       find_reactor   user_id

1       1                    1                   1             2

2       0                     1                  0             1
```

Here suppose whose `user_id = 2` has logged in the site. and need to set the permission for the below `views.py` functions.

> views.py:

```
def home(request):
    """ This function for home screen . """

    return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})


def view_reactor(request):
    """ This function for to get serch screen. """

    return render(request, 'plant/view_reactor.html',
                        {'count': 1})
```

Here I need to use like decorator function `i.e-@permission_required and @login_required`. Suppose `user_id=2` has logged in then then it will check the all permission in DB like `control_reactor=1,view_reactor=1,find_reactor=1` and all will check for `home` function and for `view_reactor` function it will check `view_reactor=1` or not . and same process for `user_id=1` also. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
from functools import wraps

def custom_permission_check(func):
    @wraps(func) # so that you can use help() method.
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        func_name = func.__name__ # get function name
        request = args[0] # get request from args
        permission_criteria = {
            'home':['control_reactor', 'view_reactor', 'find_reactor'],
            'control_reactor':['control_reactor'],
        }
        qs = Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        for per in permission_criteria[func_name]:
            qs.filter(**{per: 1}) # use variable for field
        if not qs.exists(): # when it doesn't pass
            render(request, 'somepage.html', {}) # permission denied page
        return result
    return wrapper

@custom_permission_check
def control_reactor(request):
    return render( ... )

@ custom_permission_check
def home(request):
    return render( ... )
```

Comment: Let me to check it and let you know ?

Comment: Its throwing some error. `Exception Value:  

Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: control_reactor, find_reactor, id, user_id, user_id_id, view_reactor` when I called the `view_reactor` function.

Comment: see this `permission_criteria = {
            'home':['control_reactor', 'view_reactor', 'find_reactor'],
            'control_reactor':['control_reactor'],
            'view_reactor':['view_reactor'],
            'find_reactor':['find_reactor'],
        }`. I added extra.

Comment: well, Django should know that user is user_id smartly. Can you check if other codes are fine by changing just `filter(user=1)`?

Comment: Actually I have `user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)` in my model class.

Comment: then `filter(user_id=request.user)`

Comment: ok for one user `view_reactor=0` in my database but still it access.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45670155/6568309 please take time to read manual. I think this is what you want to make. I thought you want to make Permission class yourself for some purpose. I think if you use Permission, User, Group Class which Django have as default, your problem would be solved cleanly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151866/discussion-between-subhra-and-jayground).