# How to check the permissions as per authenticated user using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need to check the permission required as per authenticate user Using Django and Python. I am providing my code below.

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    """docstring for Permission"""

    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_reactor", "1"),
            ("find_reactor", "1"),
            ("controll_reactor", "0"),
        )
```

Views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required


def view_reactor(request):
    """ This function for to get serch screen. """

    return render(request, 'plant/view_reactor.html',
                        {'count': 1})
```

Here I need to check `@permission_required` decorator function as per proper `userid`. Suppose the logged in user has permission `("view_reactor", "1"),` then that `view_reactor` function can access if  `("view_reactor", "0")` then it can not be accessed.

Comment: where do you store a user's permission? meta certainly can not store these things. You have to have a class variable to store permission and then check

Comment: Can you share your idea by one post based on my requirement ?

Comment: [This](https://ghrhome.gitbooks.io/djangoknowhow/using_the_django_authentication_system/the_permission_required_decorator.html) might help you

Answer (score 1):

you add extra permissions to your model, where first value is a name of permission and second is a human readable name, (details here [meta permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#permissions)) so if i understand you need added it to your `Reactor` model for example:

```
class Reactor(models.Model):
    # ^^^^^^
    # ....
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_reactor", "can view reactor"),
            ("find_reactor", "can find reactor"),
            ("controll_reactor", "can controll reactor"),
        )
```

and the you can use in views

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('reactor.view_reactor')
def view_reactor(request):
```

sorry  if i misunderstood

Comment: Then how to change the permission means suppose I dont want to give all three permission to a particular user . How will be that case.

Comment: you need make migrations and migrate, then distribute this rights in a standard way

Comment: meta classes can not be different for different rows in the db so how a user's permission will be different from other user? You might want to explain the standard way you mentioned above

Comment: I think This question is duplicated with one @subhra asked. Well, I gave answer with understand that you made own Permission class. Is there any reason that you don't need built in Permission, Group, User relationship in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use User, Permission, Group Class which Django have as default?

```
models.py in exampleApp
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

if you do 'makemigration' and 'migrate', It create 'add_examplemodel', 'change_examplemodel', 'delete_examplemodel' automatically. You can check auto_permission table in DB.

```
models.py in exampleApp
class ExampleModel2(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    class Meta:
        permissions = ( (permission_code, human_readable_permission_name), )
```

if you do 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' with that model, it doesn't create three default permissions but just one you named in Meta class. (It works when you create model, not when you edit)

You can just add permissions in Admin page.

It's just adding permission name in Permission class. You need to set permission for User.

you can give permission in User like this.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=someidnumber)
# User and Permissions Class have manytomany relationship.
user.permissions_set.add(permission, ... )
# you can set user 1 have one permission like view_reactor.
# you can set user 2 have two permission like view_reactor, find_reactor.
# you can give permissions to each user independently.
```

Then, you can use `@permission_required decorator`

if you want to user 1 have view_reactor permission. Just give permission user 1 by `User.objects.get(id=user1_id).permissions_set.add(view_reactor permission)`. Then `@permission_required decorator` will check.

Please read manual below.

[Adding Permission in Manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

[permission_required decorator in manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)

Comment: I will declare this class `class ExampleModel(models.Model):` in models.py file right ?@Jayground.

Comment: You don't have to do that. you can just add permission in Admin page. if you are making empty Model for putting just permission in Permission class, I think just adding in Admin page would be better.

Comment: I mean these defined classes where I have to write.